# Api methods free of Token authentication in Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

So I have implemented a token authentication system on my Django web server following the guide from this tutorial:
http://cheng.logdown.com/posts/2015/10/27/how-to-use-django-rest-frameworks-token-based-authentication
but a token is needed in every single api call otherwise I get a unauthorised error. I need to have some api calls free, meaning that anyone, not only a registered user(who will have a token of course) can call it. How is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the article you have probably set the authentication scheme on a global bases in your settings.

If you only want to have authentication for a few select views, you must not set it globally but per view as explained here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```